# How to change UITextField when edited

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

When my UITextField is pressed and type commences, my UITextField is covered up. Is there a way to move it up or move the keyboard? If so, what function would I do that in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)